# Add javascript object to existing object key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple rows (invoices) with some data including "client ID". I would like to generate an object with each client ID and the corresponding invoices. The current function I have looks like this :

```
var clients = {};
        $('.invoice').each(function() {
            var invoiceid = $(this).find('.invoiceid').text();
            var clientid = $(this).find('.client').text();
            var providerid = $(this).find('.provider').text();
            var amount = $(this).find('.amount').text();
            
            clients[clientid] = { 
                'invoiceid': invoiceid,
                'providerid': providerid,
                'amount': amount,
            };
        });
```

Problem is each new invoice with a same client ID will overwrite the previous ones because I can't have duplicate keys. So I need to have a first level "client" in which I add the different invoices. This kind of structure :

```
 var clients = {
         client-abc123: {
             invoice-456xyz: {
                 provider: john
                 amount : 123
             },
             invoice-789ghi: {
                 provider: mark
                 amount : 45
             }
         }
         client-iop654: {
             ...
         }
     }
```

I suppose one way to do it would be for each invoice to check if the client key exists ; if not create it and then add the invoice to that client key. But I'm kinda new to objects and after many tries I can't find the right way to proceed.

Comment: Why not use an array of objects? clientId will be the key, and the value will be an array, each element (an object) representing a single invoice

Answer (score 0):

A more appropriate data structure in this use case would be to create an array of objects. The objects would contain the information about the client, with each invoice as a child array. You can use `map()` to achieve this:

```js
var clients = $('.invoice').map((i, el) => {
  const $invoice = $(el);
  
  return {
    invoiceid: $invoice.find('.invoiceid').text(),
    clientid: $invoice.find('.client').text(),
    providerid: $invoice.find('.provider').text(),
    amount: $invoice.find('.amount').text()
  }
});
```

This will provide you an array in this format:

```
[{
  invoiceid: 'invoice 1',
  clientid: 'client 1'
  providerid: 'provide 1'
  amount: 'amount 1'
},{
  invoiceid: 'invoice 2',
  clientid: 'client 2'
  providerid: 'provide 2'
  amount: 'amount 2'
}]
```

If you then need to find all invoices for a specific `clientid`, you can use `filter()` or `find()`.

Comment: The callback to [jQuery's `.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) takes index first, then the element that's at that index. In addition, jQuery also has [`.filter()` which takes a function](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) thus the filtering can be done before rather than after.

Comment: @VLAZ thank you - absolute schoolboy mistake :)